# RemoveAll(s => s == null) What ‘s this line code mean？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is this line code mean? RemoveAll(s => s == null)

`allhuman.RemoveAll(s => s == null);`

can I replace it to the following code？

```
for (int i = 0; i < allhuman.Count; i++)
   {
      if(allhuman[i] == null)
      {
           allhuman.RemoveAt(i);
       }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your proposed code is removing items would rearrange the indexes

Comment: Why write the mechanism yourself when a method that does it, and is named to clearly indicate what it does, already exists? And no, that code is flawed.

Comment: @Martheen: It's not that it rearranges the indexes. You'd expect that if it's removing items. The problem is that after removing a `null` element, if the next one is also `null`, it doesn't get removed because it shifts to the index of the removed item and the loop looks at the *next* index in the next iteration.

Comment: And that's because the indexes are rearranged

Comment: Yes, it ignores that fact and doesn't do a simple `--i;` after calling `RemoveAt`. *That's* the problem: it's **naive**. Shifting indexes is not a *problem*, just a fact you have to be aware of and account for accordingly.

Comment: Why would you ask us a question that you can simply test for yourself? When you properly test both code snippets, do you get the same results?

Comment: Try it and see..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > What is this line code mean? `allhuman.RemoveAll(s => s == null);`

   It removes all elements `s` for which the expression `s == null` returns `true`. Or in other words, all elements which fulfill the condition `== null`.

   In those expressions the `s` is like the iterator in `foreach(var s in allhuman)`
2. > can I replace it to the following code?

   There is a mistake in your code since you **remove elements from the list while iterating** it. If you remove one element, next element gets the current index and will be skiped in the next iteration. Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CgWDh7

   ```
   List<object> allhuman = new List<object>{null, null, 1};
   for (int i = 0; i < allhuman.Count; i++)
   {       
       if (allhuman[i] == null)
       {
          allhuman.RemoveAt(i);
       }
   }

   allhuman.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x ?? "null"));
   ```

   =>

   ```
   null
   1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
allhuman.RemoveAll(s => s == null);
```

To remove null records where s is null

Comment: You cannot use the old way(the code which OP has written using loop), it will break the collection indexes, you cannot remove an item and move forward. If OP wants to use loop he has to iterate backwards to remove an item.

Comment: I think for someone (like OP) who doesn't necessarily know how lambda expressions work your explanation is quite useless ;)

Comment: thnx next time :)